# How to add another FragmentActivity that is into MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

I got my `MainActivity` class **extends** as `AppCompatActivity` but I want to add a new activity as below. I tried to use intent to add it into the MainActivity. However, when I open the app, it crashes when I trigger the function. Here are the codes for two activities.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.michael.jared.navigationdrawerloginsqlite;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawable;
import android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.michael.jared.navigationdrawerloginsqlite.database.DatabaseManagerUser;
import com.michael.jared.navigationdrawerloginsqlite.entity.User;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DatabaseManagerUser databaseManagerUser;
private User itemUsuario;
private String ident;
public ViewPagerActivity vpa;

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //se agrego codigo del 39 al 68
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    ident = b.getString("IDENT");

    databaseManagerUser= new DatabaseManagerUser(getApplicationContext());
    itemUsuario = databaseManagerUser.getUsuario(ident); // encuentra al usuario registrado en la bbdd

    View header = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);

    ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_nombre_usuario_menu)).setText(itemUsuario.getNombre());
    ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tv_correo_menu)).setText(itemUsuario.getCorreo());

    Bitmap bitmapsinfoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.imagen);
    RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmapsinfoto);
    roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto.setCircular(true);

    ((ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawablesinfoto);

    if(itemUsuario.getBytes()!=null){
        byte[] foodImage = itemUsuario.getBytes();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);

        ((ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)((ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap2);
        roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);

        ((ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.imageView)).setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
    }


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FirstFragment())
                .commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new SecondFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new ThirdFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_fourth_layout) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame
                        , new FourthFragment())
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewPagerActivity.class));

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
  }
}
```

**ViewPagerActivity.java**

```
package com.michael.jared.navigationdrawerloginsqlite;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.TextView;



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
ScrollTabHolder, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

public static final boolean NEEDS_PROXY = Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).intValue() < 11;

private View mHeader;

private PagerSlidingTabStrip mPagerSlidingTabStrip;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

private int mMinHeaderHeight;
private int mHeaderHeight;
private int mMinHeaderTranslation;

private TextView info;
private int mLastY;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.min_header_height);
    mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
    mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHeader = findViewById(R.id.header);
    info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

    mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

    mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mLastY=0;
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // nothing
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    if (positionOffsetPixels > 0) {
        int currentItem = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

        SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
        ScrollTabHolder currentHolder;

        if (position < currentItem) {
            currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);
        } else {
            currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position + 1);
        }

        if (NEEDS_PROXY) {
            // TODO is not good
            currentHolder.adjustScroll(mHeader.getHeight() - mLastY);
            mHeader.postInvalidate();
        } else {
            currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() + mHeader.getTranslationY()));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
    ScrollTabHolder currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);
    if(NEEDS_PROXY){
        //TODO is not good
        currentHolder.adjustScroll(mHeader.getHeight()-mLastY);
        mHeader.postInvalidate();
    }else{
        currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() +mHeader.getTranslationY()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int pagePosition) {
    if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == pagePosition) {
        int scrollY = getScrollY(view);
        if(NEEDS_PROXY){
            //TODO is not good
            mLastY=-Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation);
            info.setText(String.valueOf(scrollY));
            mHeader.scrollTo(0, mLastY);
            mHeader.postInvalidate();
        }else{
            mHeader.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {
    // nothing
}

public int getScrollY(AbsListView view) {
    View c = view.getChildAt(0);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int top = c.getTop();

    int headerHeight = 0;
    if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
        headerHeight = mHeaderHeight;
    }

    return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
}

public static float clamp(float value, float max, float min) {
    return Math.max(Math.min(value, min), max);
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> mScrollTabHolders;
    private final String[] TITLES = { "Page 1", "Page 2", "Page 3", "Page 4"};
    private ScrollTabHolder mListener;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();
    }

    public void setTabHolderScrollingContent(ScrollTabHolder listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        ScrollTabHolderFragment fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) SampleListFragment.newInstance(position);

        mScrollTabHolders.put(position, fragment);
        if (mListener != null) {
            fragment.setScrollTabHolder(mListener);
        }
     return fragment;
    }

    public SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> getScrollTabHolders() {
        return mScrollTabHolders;
    }

   }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your app crashes please add a crash log, and then try to paste the code that is only relevant to the error. That way people don't have to read through a wall of code :)

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` for this module.

Comment: posted both error and xml.